# SQL Query, multiples COUNTS en multiples tablas

Tags: sql, tablas

busco obtener la cantidad de pedidos que tiene una cotización y la cantidad de articulos que tiene ese pedido, forzosamente debe estar agrupado por cliente, pero lo que obtengo son datos iguales para todos los counts.

Este es le query que uso:

```
SELECT T2.id,T1.id_ticket,
       T2.f_registro,
       T2.cliente,
       COUNT(T2.id) as cots ,
       COUNT(T1.id_ticket) as pedido , 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T3.num_control > 0 THEN 1 END ) as partidas,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T3.estatus = 'Aprobado' THEN 1 END) as p_fin 
FROM crm_pedidos T1,crm_tickets T2, crm_cotizacion T3 
WHERE 1=1 AND T1.id_ticket=T2.id AND T3.id_ticket=T2.id 
GROUP BY T2.cliente ORDER BY T2.f_registro DESC
```

[image: Me devuelve las columnas con el mismo numero cuando todos son diferentes]

Comment: En el `GROUP BY` debe de ir también las columnas renombradas

Comment: Prueba con `COUNT(DISTINCT T2.id) as cots` y `COUNT(DISTINCT T1.id_ticket) as pedido`

Comment: Muchas gracias, el DISTINCT arreglo gran parte del problema

Answer (score 0):

Primero, y quizás lo más importante, por favor utiliza la sintaxis JOIN en las consultas. Es más legible para queries más extensas con diferentes tipos de JOINs (Left Join, Outer Join, Right Join).

Segundo, por las comas, se intuye estás haciendo un inner join. En SQL Server (no nos dices si es MySql, o SQL Server), el motor de base de datos evalúa las siguientes sentencias en ese orden:

1-. FROM y JOINs. Se ejecutan primero para saber cuántos dataset y tablas estarán incluidas en la consulta.

2-. WHERE

3-. GROUP BY

4-. HAVING

5-. **SELECT**.

Si lo notas, **SELECT** se ejecuta una vez que el motor ya sabe cuáles tablas, cuáles relaciones y cuáles filtros aplicará a los dataset.

Esto es importante porque, al momento que realizas los SELECT Count, tu dataset únicamente tiene 13 resultados. Es muy probable que si eliminas el Group By, veas que hay 13 resultados únicamente. Al realizar el count, sólo contará 13.

Espero esto te ayude